# Creating controllers in Views

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a view - `PageView` - whose output is the concatenation of multiple `ModuleView` outputs. I'd wish to always initialize views (if necessary) and models in controllers. The reason for this is that I find it easy to initialize the given view based on controller action (many models are associated with multiple views, ie.: front-end and back-end views).

**Am I to be beheaded if I initialize a controller in a view? If yes, what approach would you recommend to solve the issue of a view being the concatenation of other views?**

**PHP code**

```
class PageView
{
    public function Output()
    {
        # $this->modules was set by a method called from PageController
        foreach ($this->modules as $module)
        {
            $module_controller = new ModuleController();

            # Will initialize ModuleModel (ID of 23 in constructor) and ModuleView, then call ModuleView->Output(ModuleModel->GetData())
            $module_controller->ShowFrontEnd(array('module_id' => 23));
        }
    }
}
```

The project is AJAX heavy, hence the need for page and module controllers. The goal is to offer easy extensibility and readibility by those who are experienced with the MVC pattern in PHP.

Comment: So you are calling a controller method from a view, to get its content, as part of another view?

Comment: @didierc Almost. I'm calling a controller method from the current view, to get another view's output into the current view.

Comment: Aw, that's what I meant, I got confused.

Comment: You should do it the other way round: generate the sub view data from the main controller by calling the other controller's  method, and then generate the view with all the necessary data prepared.

Comment: The interesting question is : why you should not do it as you planned? The goal is to keep each development layer clearly separated, so that for instance designers don't need to know how the app is implemented  to design their templates. If you mix up views and controllers, they are not loosely coupled anymore.

Comment: Now when I think about it: pattern-wise, there is nothing against making the PageController create module views and models, right? This seems like a pretty logical and straightforward approach to me.

Comment: People prefer using injection as much as possible: set everything up through configuration files, and let the engine build the controllers, views,  invoke services, etc. That said, if you are maintaining the whole stack, you'd want to keep it as simple as possible, but if you are using a third party middleware solution, you want it to be as flexible as possible. And as I hinted at, there's the size and composition of your team. Doing all by yourself? Pick whatever model works best for you, even if it means breaking best practices.

Comment: @didierc Yes, the method I ended up using was similar, if not the same as the one you mentioned: I created the module controllers inside the page controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be beheaded. Controllers should be spawning/handling views, not the other way around. It is no longer MVC if you are initializing Controllers from a View.

Comment: Actually you both are wrong. Controllers and Views should be spawned by the "front controller"